# User settings are deleted on update in Outlook VSTO addins

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I got an Outlook VSTO addins using `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase` to store application preferences.

It's mostly code generated by Visual Studio, and it's working fine using

```
MySettings.Default.foo = "bar"
```

Apparently those settings are stored inside `{USER_DIR}\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\MyPlugin.vsto_v_Path_{SOME_HASH}\{SOME_VERSION}\user.config`.

However, when the addins update, a new directory seems to be created and old preferences are deleted.

I tried to add `MySettings.Default.upgrade()` on VSTO start, but it seems to remove all settings on start.

Is it possible to have persistant settings across upgrades ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your custom data between application updates I'd recommend choosing another folder. For example, your add-in may create a subfolder in the `<AppData>/Roaming` folder. The `AppData` folder contains application (app) settings, files, and data specific to the application (apps) on your Windows PC. The folder is hidden by default in Windows File Explorer and has three hidden sub-folders: Local, LocalLow, and Roaming.

This *Roaming* folder (`%appdata%`) contains data that can move with your user profile from PC to PC—like when you're on a domain—because this data has the ability to sync with a server. For example, if you sign in to a different PC on a domain, your web browser favorites or bookmarks will be available.

Read more about that in the [What Is the AppData Folder in Windows?](https://www.howtogeek.com/318177/what-is-the-appdata-folder-in-windows/) article.

Comment: I did not see any option with `ApplicationSettingsBase` for setting a custom path. Did I miss something ?